# To get Sql Server 2008 r2 installed, do I just install Sql Server 2008 and then use windows update?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been told I need to install Sql Server  2008 r2 on my development PC, do I just install Sql Server 2008 and then let windows update install r2 – e.g. is it like any other service pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, SQL 2008 R2 is a completely separate release from 2008, it is not a hotfix or service pack.  You must install clean or do an in-place upgrade.

Comment: thanks, I will get it down loaded from our MSDN subscription

Answer (score 1):

..or you can do a side by side install, but please be aware some of the shared components will be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

As squillman and retracement said it completely separate but it's also inexpensive. Prices fluctuate on Amazon but I've seen R2 for as low as 42 bucks and you can put it on multiple machines, as long as they aren't production machines.

Comment: To clarify this, $42 would be for SQL Developer Edition which is expressly targeted toward single devloper, no production installations.  It may not (legally) be used in any form production environment or by more than one developer.